# Did Dark Star have a scene showing images of possible target stars or planets?

Tags: dark-star

I watched *Dark Star* last night, not having seen it since 1984.  (Weirdly, it triggered a nightmare about the much scarier *The Thing*.  My subconscious apparently just recognizes John Carpenter's signature style.)  However, a short scene I thought I remembered seemed to be missing.  Early in the film, as the crew on the bridge are discussing new possible targets, I remembered there being a scene showing either stars or planets on a CRT monitor.  I *think* it was a three or four nearby stars, showing a still image of each star, with one of the crew announcing that it had some number of planets, but they were all stable.  Alternatively, it might have been a list of the planets around the nearby red dwarf that the crew locates.  There was a mention of that star, with all stable planets, in the version I saw, but there was no monitor image.

When I saw it at a science fiction convention in 1984, it was a film print, presumably from the original release.  The version I watched yesterday was just one I found on the Internet.  It could have been a television edit or otherwise trimmed version.  Of course, after more than thirty-five years, I could just be misremembering.  So was this scene part if the original cut of *Dark Star* or not?

Comment: "The original cut of Dark Star was a 45 minute long film school project shot on 16mm film. After touring a few festivals, producer Jack Harris stepped in and put up additional funds to stretch it to feature length and transfer it to 35mm (a more common format for theatrical distribution). Carpenter and O'Bannon produced a 72 minute cut, only for Harris to tack on an additional ten minutes of excised footage to round the runtime to a more commercially desirable figure."

Answer (score 2):

[According](https://web.archive.org/web/20191031103638/https://www.bbfc.co.uk/releases/dark-star-1970-0) to the British Board of Film Classification, the running time was 83 minutes when released in the UK. Therefore [this Youtube video](https://youtu.be/jZUhSqgBEAI?t=423), which is also 83 minutes long, likely represents the full released movie.  (Perhaps this is the one you watched in 2021).

Beginning at 0:07:03 (linked) is the start of the scene you mention, immediately before the opening credits, about looking for the next possible target. I don't see any displays showing planets or stars, just face shots and conversation.

There are no other scenes where they are discussing target selection, either.

As mentioned by @FuzzyBoots, the movie was lengthened twice. 17 minutes were added between the film school project and the festival tour; and 10 more minutes were added for the theatrical release totalling 83 minutes. The site [www.movie-censorship.com](http://www.movie-censorship.com) [compares](https://www.movie-censorship.com/report.php?ID=706907) the second and third versions, and also mentions a "bonus version" present on the UK DVD, that the site here theorizes could be Carpenter's reconstruction of the original film school project.  The comparison on the website between the 72 minute and 83 minute cuts does not reveal any monitor shots that were dropped.

So I guess the answer to your question is **No**, there is no scene with a monitor display of several stars or planets, and you are probably misremembering.